# Azure Redis Cache - add_ServerMaintenanceEvent from StackExchange.Redis ConnectionMultiplexer pool does not have an implementation

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, connection-pooling, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I was creating a library in .net core 6 for using with other projects.I am trying to add cache pooling using StackExchange.Redis.MultiplexerPool in that library.

```
public class Library1 : ILibrary1
{
      public Library1(IConfiguration configuration, string azureOptionsKey)
    {
        configuration.Bind(azureOptionsKey, azureOptions);
         
        //redis client
        _redisClient = new LibraryRedisCacheService();
    }
}
```

below is my CacheService

```
public class LibraryRedisCacheService 
{
    private readonly IConnectionMultiplexerPool _connectionMultiplexerPool;
    private readonly int[] _connectionsErrorCount;

    public LibraryRedisCacheService()
    {
        var configureOptions = ConfigurationOptions.Parse("Cache connection string");
        configureOptions.AllowAdmin = true;
        configureOptions.AsyncTimeout = 10000;

        _connectionMultiplexerPool = ConnectionMultiplexerPoolFactory.Create(
            poolSize: 10,
            configurationOptions: configureOptions,
            connectionSelectionStrategy: ConnectionSelectionStrategy.RoundRobin);
        
        _connectionsErrorCount = new int[_connectionMultiplexerPool.PoolSize];
    }

    public async Task<TResult> QueryRedisAsync<TResult>(Func<IDatabase, Task<TResult>> op)
    {
        var connection = await _connectionMultiplexerPool.GetAsync();

        try
        {
            return await op(connection.Connection.GetDatabase());
        }
        catch (RedisConnectionException)
        {
            _connectionsErrorCount[connection.ConnectionIndex]++;

            if (_connectionsErrorCount[connection.ConnectionIndex] < 3)
            {
                throw;
            }

            await connection.ReconnectAsync();

            return await op(connection.Connection.GetDatabase());
        }
    }

    public async Task SetCacheAsync<T>(string key, T value, TimeSpan? expiry = null, int retryCount = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            await QueryRedisAsync(async db => await db.StringSetAsync(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value), expiry ?? TimeSpan.FromHours(12)));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (retryCount < 3)
            {
                await Task.Delay(3000);
                await SetCacheAsync(key, value, expiry, retryCount + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<T?> GetCacheAsync<T>(string key, int retryCount = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var value = await QueryRedisAsync(async db => await db.StringGetAsync(key));
            return !value.HasValue ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (retryCount < 3)
            {
                await Task.Delay(3000);
                await GetCacheAsync<T>(key, retryCount + 1);
            }
        }
        return default;
    }

    public async Task<TResult> RetryCachConnectAsync<TResult>(Func<IConnectionMultiplexer, TResult> op)
    {
        var connection = await _connectionMultiplexerPool.GetAsync();

        try
        {
            return op(connection.Connection);
        }

        catch (RedisConnectionException)
        {
            _connectionsErrorCount[connection.ConnectionIndex]++;

            if (_connectionsErrorCount[connection.ConnectionIndex] < 3)
            {
                throw;
            }

            await connection.ReconnectAsync();

            return op(connection.Connection);
        }
    }

    }
}
```

and in my project startup i am adding this library like this

```
services.AddSingleton<ILibrary1, Library1>(
           _ => new Library1(Configuration, "KeyvaultReference"));
```

after that i am getting run time exception in my application like below

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Method 'add_ServerMaintenanceEvent' in type 'StackExchange.Redis.MultiplexerPool.Multiplexers.InternalDisposableConnectionMultiplexer' from assembly 'StackExchange.Redis.MultiplexerPool, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

How to add this method implementation, Or I am doing something wrong in the library implementation